# How to generate drop down menu selections to populate a form based on row/record form data available in a database?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

OK so I've been trying to figure this one out for a couple weeks now...I've tried different scenarios and alternative methods and have come to find that my frustration is overriding the pleasure and I feel like I want to give up on this.  What I really need is someone who can provide some truly helpful guidance.  Not to just provide code but actually explain how and why it works.  Point in the right direction maybe...  Thanks.

I'm trying to generate drop down menu selections for a form based on row/record form data available in a database.

If records are available...I'm trying to figure out a way to have those records available as a selection under the drop-down menu that then populate the form when selected.

The drop-down menu selections generated I thought maybe could be labelled with the text/value of another column's value within the same row/record "invoice_id"

***The drop-down menu should only be generated if 2 values match.***

The preloaded default value of a html form's hidden input "user_email"
**&**
The value under the "user_email" column in the database

**FORM**

```
<form action="xxx.php" class="well" id="xxx" name"xxx" method="post"> 

<input type="hidden" id="user_email" name="user_email" value="xxx@email.com">
<input type="text" id="invoice_id" name="invoice_id">


//This is the selection box

<select id="other1" name="other1">
<option value="">Please select...</option> 
 <option value="select1">Select option 1</option>
 <option value="select2">Select option 2</option>
</select>


//These are the checkbox inputs

<input type="hidden" name="other2" value="0" />
<input type="checkbox" name="other2" value="1" onclick="return false" checked/>Agree to terms of service.


//These are the radio buttion inputs

<input type="radio" onclick="change" name="other3" value="1.00" />Option1
<input type="radio" onclick="change" name="other3" value="2.00" />Option2


<input type="submit" value="Submit">

</form>
```

**Database Structure**

http://oi60.tinypic.com/69f0us.jpg

Comment: Proper DDLs please, not pictures.

Comment: I'm sorry i dont even know how to find or provide that information

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/fv4ph54t/)?

Answer (score 0):

You want to dynamically fill a select with rows from a database?
Is it to select an invoice?
More info would be great we can not just guess what you exactly want to do.

If you want to ad a dynamic list you at least need javascript or php to generate the html.
The generated html will look like other1.

```
<select id="listBox" > 
<?php 
    foreach($items as $key=>$value)
    {
?>
    <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"> <?php echo $value; ?>
    </option> 
<?php } ?>
</select>
```

http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

Does this answer your question?
And please look for a framework for future projects

Comment: I want users to be able to prefill a form with data that they have submitted in the past.